# Query Not Working for All (in Hash)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query:

```
var People = db.People
.Where(p => studyDesignHashset.All(x => p.StudyDesign.StartsWith(x) || p.StudyDesign.EndsWith(x) || p.StudyDesign.Contains("|" + x + "|")))
.Select(c => new { p.ID, p.StudyDesign }).Distinct();
```

studyDesignHashset is a hashset that takes all filters a person inputs, such as cat and dog.

```
var studyDesignHashset = new HashSet<string> { };
```

The table db.People is set up as so:

```
ID    StudyDesign
1     cat|dog
2     bird|fish|cat
```

and so on.

However, my filtering is not working.  Say the person inputs cat and dog for filters.  I am getting back #1 and #2, which is not correct.  What am I doing wrong with the query logic?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

When I try this:

```
var pq1 = db.People;
foreach (var f in studyDesignHashset)
    pq1 = pq1.Where(p => p.StudyDesign.StartsWith(f) || p.StudyDesign.EndsWith(f) || p.StudyDesign.Contains("|" + f + "|"));

var People = pq1.Select(c => new { p.ID, p.StudyDesign });
```

I get 0 results back.  I printed the SQL statement, and if I run it in SQL server directly, it says `Must declare the scalar variable "@p__linq__0".`

Comment: I never used All inside a linq query so while at first glance it should work, I would look at a trace to see the exact SQL that's generated, maybe that gives you an idea.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: I stripped it down bare, and I actually am getting nothing back. (the two results I did get were from another related query.)

Comment: I wouldn't think you need the `.Distinct()` for the query.

Comment: My SQL connection won't allow `.All()` on a local `HashSet`.

Comment: @NetMage So what do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `HashSet` is small, you can put each criteria in the query

```
var pq1 = db.People;
foreach (var f in studyDesignHashset)
    pq1 = pq1.Where(p => p.StudyDesign.StartsWith(f) || p.StudyDesign.EndsWith(f) || p.StudyDesign.Contains("|" + f + "|"));

var People = pq1.Select(c => new { p.ID, p.StudyDesign });
```

Comment: Had to add this so it didn't throw an error: IQueryable<People> pq1 = db.People; but it is still returning 0.

Comment: What do you mean, returning 0? Is People empty? Before you said you were getting #1 and #2 (e.g. any match). Also, have you ever used LINQPad?

Comment: Yes, I am doing a count of the results, and it is 0.  I also try appending the results to a string, and the string remains empty.

Comment: I have not used that program and don't have the time to learn another application.

Comment: I tried printing out the query, and it gives me this error if I run it directly: Must declare the scalar variable "@p__linq__0".